# Ruby Selenium - How to identify elements based on attributes at runtime

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have a table that has a column called "request submitted" , if submitted it's checked else it's not, I want to collect the classes responsible of checked or not checked to do some testing, here are the two options when expecting the html code :

```
//*[@id="main-display"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]/button/i

<i aria-label="consent received" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
```

AND

```
//*[@id="main-display"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]/i


<i aria-label="<span class=&quot;translation_missing&quot; title=&quot;translation missing: en.aria.consent.'not_'received&quot;>'Not 'Received</span>" class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
```

I want to collect `"fa-check-circle"` and `"fa-circle-thin"` in an array , here is what I did :

```
Then /^I select request submitted$/ do

req_submitted = $driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//*[@id='main- display']/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody//i")
# consent_values = consents.map { |consent| consent.attribute('class')[3..-1]}
puts req_submitted
ar = []
req_s = req_submitted.map do |r|
case r.attribute('class')
when "fa fa-check-circle" then ar.push('fa-check-circle')
when "fa fa-circle-thin" then ar.push('fa-circle-thin')
else nil
  end   
 end
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just use `//i[contains(@class, "fa-check-circle")]` and `//i[contains(@class, "fa-circle-thin")]` to collect elements of each type

Comment: Thanks Anderson, I will try it tomorrow, is there any way to collect both of them in the same time in one array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would give your expected result

```
array=[driver.find_elements(xpath: "//i[@class='fa fa-check-circle']"), driver.find_elements(xpath: "//i[@class='fa fa-circle-thin']")]
    .flatten
    .map{|element|element.attribute('class').split.last}

p array
```

Update:

As you asked,  Below code prints `true` If all elements are same

```
result=(array.uniq.count.eql? (1)) ? true : false

p result
```

If you want to check specifically check for `fa-check-circle` then write the below code

```
p array.map{|x|x.eql?'fa-check-circle'}.all?

#=> true if all elements are 'fa-check-circle' otherwise false
```

Comment: Anderson, Rajagopalan, thanks lot, this what I was looking for. is there any way to test if array has only the same elements 'fa-check-circle' ? thanks lot

Comment: @Fatna I have answered your other question as well, Did that answer your question? `RUBY : selenium webdriver alert is not working`

Comment: @Fatna You wanted to check whether array only has `fa-check-circle` not `fa-circle-thin` ?

Comment: @Fatna Updated the answer, just have a look at it.

Comment: Rajagopalan, you code is good, clean and rubist, I did this array.each do |r|
      puts r
      expect(r).to eq('fa-check-circle') 
 end   BUT I prefer yours in an expect test to true

Comment: @Fatna Okay thank you, did you check my other answer to your question? Regarding to alert?

Comment: thanks lot, am going to check it after I finish this, still have a small question, if I am using expect(array.map{|x|x.eql?'fa-check-circle'}.all?).to eq(true)  , how to have this solution working even if the array has nothing (empty array) after the search (filter)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169255/discussion-between-fatna-and-rajagopalan).

Comment: @Fatna you want to check whether array is empty. ? If so, there is a method called `empty?`

Comment: @Fatna we will do it tomorrow, my office hours are over now, I don't have laptop in my hand.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question it seems you want to collect the elements either with *class* attribute as **fa fa-check-circle** or *class* attribute as **fa fa-circle-thin**. So you can optimize your *Locator Strategy* as follows :

```
req_submitted = $driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//i[contains(@class,'fa')][contains(@class,'fa-check-circle') or contains(@class,'fa-circle-thin')]")
```

**Note** : As you mentioned that you want to collect "fa-check-circle" and "fa-circle-thin" in an array, of-coarse *fa-check-circle* and *fa-circle-thin* both won't be present together in any case and you can use `find_element()` instead.

Comment: OP doesn't want elements, OP wants string either `fa-check-circle` or `fa-circle-thin` from the selected elements(In your case it's `req_submitted `), Please see my answer.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I think some where in the question I saw **I want to collect "fa-check-circle" and "fa-circle-thin" in an array** and of-coarse _fa-check-circle_ and _fa-circle-thin_ both won't be present together.

Comment: No no, you misunderstood the question, S/he meant to say element which has `fa-check-circle` and also element which has `fa-circle-thin`.

Comment: Ummm, interesting !!! See OP mantioned _I want to collect the classes responsible of checked or not checked to do some testing_, so we are just identifying the element based on the presence of a certain class. Of-coarse you can retrieve any of the attributes e.g. `class`, `aria-label`, etc anytime.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but out of that element she needs the attribute values in an array except(fa ), look at that code, that's what she is trying to do.